# XSL to get exactly the same html code as in the XML element

Tags: xml, xslt

XML/XSL newbie here, so please forgive my ignorance. This is the xml input given to me:

```
<entry>
    <desc>
        <p>Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">dolor</a> sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet.</p>
    </desc>
</entry>
```

I must write an XSL to get this result:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com">dolor</a> sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet.</p>
```

I thought this would work, in an entry template:

```
<xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
```

but instead this is the output of the above line:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Am I correct in assuming there must be other xsl stylesheets on my system that do that? In any case, I have neither read not edit access to them, I can only add a new stylesheet, so to fix this I used this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="desc/*">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This gets me, at least:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

However as you can see links and formatting have gone bye bye! I have no control on the kind of html elements that get added in there. Can anybody suggest a way to preserving the formatting and all of the desc element? The engine is XSL 1 only. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy the elements under `desc` and all of their sub-elements. The [`copy-of`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp) XSL element will do this for you:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="desc/node()"/>
```

That will copy all of the children of `desc`, including text nodes, and any of their sub-elements.

Comment: Unless you're sure `<desc>` will only contain elements (no mixed content), I'd recommend using `"desc/node()"` instead, which will grab both elements and text nodes.

Comment: @Ben Blank: The example has only elements, but your point is valid. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow at work and see if it gives me the desired output.

Comment: Just to add that the reason that this is the correct answer is that xsl:value-of will return the text value of all child nodes, which is why you're only getting the Lorem Ipsum without the markup. xsl:copy-of will copy the nodes as well as their text.

Comment: Thanks guys, only had time to try it today and it works like a charm! And thanks so much carolclarinet too for the explanation, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/entry/desc">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm already inside a <pre><xsl:template match="/entry"></pre> template, which I omitted for brevity. Would the @*|node() part of the select work inside such a template? I confess I'm at a loss as on what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Your select is incorrect.

select="desc"

or

select="/entry/desc"

From http://w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp:

nodename    Selects all child nodes of the named node

/   Selects from the root node

//  Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no 
matter where they are

.   Selects the current node

..  Selects the parent of the current node

@   Selects attributes

Comment: His selectors are obviously right, otherwise he'd get no output at all. It's more likely that he's simply omitted the `for-each` or `template` declarations which establish the context around his snippets.

Comment: I omitted the "entry" template declaration for brevity, but my select does get the value of the desc element, just stripped of all formatting for reasons unknown to me.